# Best data repository to publish a large 'plotly' table containing all annotations on a transcriptome?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomes, publishing

I want to publish a transcriptome paper, along with interactive materials enabling readers to peruse the data behind the discussion. The R package 'plotly' enables rendering online-publishable tables that can be filtered & searched for specific entries.

I would like to publish such a table as supplementary to a paper (e.g. preprint version) however usually data repositories allow for uploading files and text. I intend to deposit the first version of my main manuscript to Bioarxiv, where they primarily publish .pdf files.

Would anyone here know an official data repository with a format such that would enable publishing online an interactive table?

A good example of such a table is given [here](https://butterlab.imb-mainz.de/flydev/?data=embryogenesis).

Disclaimer: I have also asked this question at SE BioInformatics. Like me, they are unsure which would be the best fitting SE Community.

Comment: Your example seems to be hosted on the website of an institute. Is there any reason you can't do/try something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Journals and services where you can submit your script and manuscript and get DOI:

- [PLOS One](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/)
- [F1000](https://f1000.com/)
- [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org/)
- [CodeOcean](https://codeocean.com)